# I am Unable to Send My email in django backend app

Tags: django, backend

When i can send post request for contact view so try block can't run and except block should be run.
Here i cant unable to send mail.
Here error in send_mail function.
So please Help me.
In Here my setting.py code

settings.py

```
 EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backend.smtp.EmailBackend'
 EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
 EMAIL_PORT=587
 EMAIL_HOST_USER='kalp2002prajapati@gmail.com'
 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='******'
 EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
 EMAIL_USE_SSL = 0
```

view.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import Contact
from django.core.mail import 
send_mail,EmailMessage
from rest_framework.response import Response
class ContactCreateView(APIView):
permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )

def post(self, request, format=None):
    data = self.request.data
    print(data)

    try:
        send_mail(
            data['subject'],
            'Name: '+ data['name']
            + '\nEmail: '+data['email']+'\nMessage:'+ data['message'],
            'kalpprajapati2002@gmail.com',
            ['kalp2002prajapati@gmail.com'],
            fail_silently=False
        )

        contact = Contact(name=data['name'], email=data['email'], subject=data['subject'], message=data['message'])
        contact.save()

        return Response({'success': 'Message sent successfully'})

    except:
        return Response({'error': 'Message failed to send'})
```

urls.py

```
  from django.urls import path
  from .views import ContactCreateView

  urlpatterns = [
      path('', ContactCreateView.as_view())
  ]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Contact(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message=models.TextField(blank=True)
    contact_date=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 0):

just delete all the self from the view, you need only the request.
if this doesn't make your code work, post the error you are getting

Comment: This should work, if the error outputs something like "self not defined" or something like that.  def's don't have self, only methods inside classes do.

Comment: i can doesn't get any error but when i can post data from postman so i can get my except block error = (error:Message failed to send )